# If I lock an item, will it be sold if I select sell all?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

You can mark items as 'locked' in your inventory, which means they cannot be given to your hero, dropped, or sold to the bank as a singular item, through disabling those respective buttons.

The 'Sell All' button, however, remains enabled. If I press this button, will it just sell the unlocked items, or will the locked items be sold as well?

Comment: You can still give an item to a hero even if it's locked.

Comment: @Mr.November Yeah, I realised that after asking, the item I was looking at in question was only usable by heroes > my level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the lock button is mainly used to prevent the item to be sold with the "Sell all" command.

I use it exclusively to do that.

Comment: What about now that there are folders - will `sell all` sell **all** items in **all** folders, or only items in the folder you're looking at *(or only items in that folder and its sub-folders)*?